# Delegação de evento apenas uma vez, em um cenário 'dinâmico'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho uma função `hello()` cujo argumento é o retorno de uma chamada de ajax:

```
function hello(msg) {
    alert(msg);
}

$.ajax({
    url: 'example.com',
    data: data
  }).done(function(resp) {
     // abre_modal
     // apenas no fecho (click close) da modal é que eu quero que a função abaixo seja executada
     $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function() { hello(resp); });
  });
```

Mas o cenário acima provoca um problema, o evento é delegado várias vezes, e como consequência a função `hello()` é executada o mesmo número de vezes.

Como faço, tendo em conta que apenas quero delegar o evento uma vez, mas a `resp` é dinâmica, para que a função seja executada apenas uma vez, assim como a delegação do evento click close da modal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não deste muito contexto ao resto do código, mas podias fazer algo assim:

```js
var resposta = '';
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
  hello(resposta);
});

$.ajax({
  url: 'example.com',
  data: data
}).done(function(resp) {
  resposta = resp;
});
```

Assim tens a variável acessível globalmente (não é o ideal mas é uma maneira de fazer). Isso só irá funcionar depois do ajax ter corrido uma vez.

Provavelmente podes também usar o `.one(` que é a maneira do jQuery correr um event handler só 1 vez.

Seria assim:

```js
function hello(msg) {
  alert(msg);
}

$.ajax({
  url: 'example.com',
  data: data
}).done(function(resp) {
  // abre_modal
  // apenas no fecho (click close) da modal é que eu quero que a função abaixo seja executada
  $('#myModal').one('hide.bs.modal', function() {
    hello(resp);
  });
});
```

Comment: Isso não tem problema porque a modal só abre quando ajax é `done()`. Entretanto consegui resolver assim: `$('#myModal').off('hide.bs.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {...});`. Mas vou aceitar a tua com certeza. Obrigado.

Comment: @HulaHula testa também com `.one(`, que o jQuery tem para correr event handlers só uma vez

Comment: Ha boa, não sabia disso não